# PHP Regular expression to disallow too short urls

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regular expression that finds urls in text and replaces them with links

```
preg_replace( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)[-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '<a href="\0" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\0</a>', $text );
```

The problem is, when someone types text that contains "i.e" it converts it also to a link, which should not happen. How do I limit this regular expression to replace strings longer than 3 characters?

I tried putting `{3,}`, but it's not working.

```
preg_replace( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)
([-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]{3,})*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', '
<a href="\0" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">\0</a>', $text );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `preg_replace_callback` to check if the text captured has at least `5` or `6` chars :

```
preg_replace_callback( '@(?<![.*">])\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|[a-z]\.)([-A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$?!:,.]{3,})*[A-Z0-9+&#/%=~_|$]@i', function($matches){
   if(strlen($matches[0])>5){
      return '<a href="'.$matches[0].'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">'.$matches[0].'</a>';
    }else{
       return $matches[0];
     }
   }, $text );
```

Comment: Great, it works! just guys remember to put 'return' in front of preg_replace_callback if you have this code wrapped in a function like text_to_url($text)

Comment: of course you have to put the return statement if you wrap it. But it was not in your question